# kernel_task takes 100% of the CPU permanently

Tags: macbook-pro, performance, cpu

I have a problem with my computer and, although I can find some discussions about it on the internet, I was so far unlucky with what I tried. So I would like to share here this issue in more details. As the title says, kernel_task takes 100% of the CPU permanently (but no problem with memory).

The computer is:

MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)

Processor 2.7 GHz Intel Core i5

Memory 16 GB 1867 MHz DDR3

Startup Disk Intel Iris Graphics 6100 1536 MB

macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6

So far I have tried to:

- Update everything on the App Store,
- Free some space because the disk was quite full,
- Remove recently installed applications,
- Do a cleaning with CCleaner and remove viruses with Bitdefender (it found Adwares in some .dmg and .pkg files that I did not remove after installing programs, so I did it after the analysis),
- Use sudo purge,
- Reset the SMC,
- Reboot in safe mode.

None of this has worked, so now I am thinking to try to upgrade to macOS Catalina (I have read it is possible but the App Store does not automatically suggest to do this) or even reinstall everything from scratch. But I am a bit skeptical about this approach which is very drastic and might not even work.

So I am coming here for help, ideas, suggestions... Should I consider that it is a possible hardware problem? Also I must say that during quite a long time I did not shut down the computer so that it was  runing all the time but not necessarily doing anything requiring a lot of CPU or memory usage.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/363337?lq=1

Comment: Given that you found viruses/malware, I would wipe the drive and restart with a clean install of macOS. Since you’ll be installing an OS from scratch,   this would be a good opportunity to upgrade to Catalina. However, considering upgrading as a solution to an issue is not a sound decision at all.  You need to solve the problem before moving forward.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. @anki I will look into the links to see if I find other solutions that I have not tried yet and hopefully the problem can be solved...

Comment: @Allan Do you know a very clear and serious tutorial to upgrade to Catalina and install from scratch, that might include using Time Machine backups. Although the malwares might be present in the back up? I am actually really new to mac computers and it is the first time I encounter a problem with a macbook. I am more used to solve problems on PC with windows... And it should be done quicly as I am using this macbook for work. :(